# Using Grafana with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I am trying to make Grafana display all my metrics (CPU, Memory, etc).

I have already configured Grafana on my server and have configured influxdb and of course I have configured Jmeter listener (Backend Listener) but still I cannot display all grpahas, any idea what should I do in order to make it work ?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail for anyone to help you. Like what happens when you to graph a query, what is the response from InfluxDB, and js errors in Grafana, etc. The more detail the better. A problem description like "cannot display graph" gives anyone willing to help almost zero information about what could be causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that system metrics (CPU/Memory, etc.) are not in the scope of the JMeter Backend Listener implementation. Actually capturing those KPIs is a part of [PerfMon plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), which currently doesn't seem to support dumping the metrics to InfluxDB/Graphite (at least it doesn't seem to work for me). It might be a good idea to raise such a request at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins. Until this gets done, I guess you also have the option of using some alternative metric-collection tools to feed data in InfluxDB/Graphite. Those would depend on the server OS you want to monitor (e.g. [Graphite-PowerShell-Functions](https://github.com/MattHodge/Graphite-PowerShell-Functions) for Windows or [collectd](https://collectd.org/) for everything else)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that JMeter posts the data to InfluxDB? Did you see the default measurements created in influxDB?

I am able to send the data using backend listener to influxdb. I have given the steps in this site.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/